# re2.cc compiling problem when bundle install for gitlab

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gitlab, re2

I'm getting the following error and wonder how should I solve it

I'm getting this error when trying to run gem install re2 -v 1.1.1
However, run gem install re2 -v 1.2.0 works perfectly for me in the same directory.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing re2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/re2-1.1.1/ext/re2
/home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -I /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20200629-12178-1dryx90.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for rb_str_sublen()... yes
checking for -lre2... yes
checking for re2 requires C++11 compiler... yes
checking for RE2::Match() with endpos argument... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/re2-1.1.1/ext/re2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/re2-1.1.1/ext/re2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling re2.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:0,
                 from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from re2.cc:9:
/home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/defines.h:286:44: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
 #   define EXTERN __pragma(message(__FILE__"("STRINGIZE(__LINE__)"): warning: "\
                                            ^
In file included from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/intern.h:24:0,
                 from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:2040,
                 from /home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from re2.cc:9:
/home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/defines.h:286:44: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
 #   define EXTERN __pragma(message(__FILE__"("STRINGIZE(__LINE__)"): warning: "\
                                            ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_scanner_scan(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:261:37: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
               p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1"));
                                     ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_matchdata_to_a(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:459:35: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
             p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1"));
                                   ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_matchdata_nth_match(int, VALUE)’:
re2.cc:483:33: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
           p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                                 ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_matchdata_inspect(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:614:29: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
       p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                             ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_initialize(int, VALUE*, VALUE)’:
re2.cc:687:19: error: ‘class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘set_utf8’
       re2_options.set_utf8(RTEST(utf8));
                   ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_inspect(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:770:29: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
       p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                             ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_to_s(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:788:29: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
       p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                             ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_utf8(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:818:42: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
   return BOOL2RUBY(p->pattern->options().utf8());
                                          ^
re2.cc:21:23: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOL2RUBY’
 #define BOOL2RUBY(v) (v ? Qtrue : Qfalse)
                       ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_error_arg(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:1015:31: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
         p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                               ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_options(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:1046:39: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
       BOOL2RUBY(p->pattern->options().utf8()));
                                       ^
re2.cc:21:23: note: in definition of macro ‘BOOL2RUBY’
 #define BOOL2RUBY(v) (v ? Qtrue : Qfalse)
                       ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_named_capturing_groups(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:1116:33: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
           p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1"),
                                 ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_Replace(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
re2.cc:1287:31: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
         p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                               ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_GlobalReplace(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)’:
re2.cc:1324:31: error: ‘const class re2::RE2::Options’ has no member named ‘utf8’
         p->pattern->options().utf8() ? "UTF-8" : "ISO-8859-1");
                               ^
re2.cc:37:36: note: in definition of macro ‘ENCODED_STR_NEW’
       int _enc = rb_enc_find_index(encoding); \
                                    ^
re2.cc: In function ‘VALUE re2_regexp_utf8(VALUE)’:
re2.cc:819:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
make: *** [re2.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/re2-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/re2-1.1.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2017-07-01 version of re2 lib for re2 gem 1.1.1